# Orbit Around 3D Sphere in Processing

Tags: javascript, 3d, processing, orbit

I'm trying to build an infinite flight simulator in processing. I want to fly over a sphere (planet) in first person view like a satellite and control the direction with the arrow keys. I don't know how to set the camera without getting a gimbal lock.

That is exactly what i want to do:

[Moving on 3D Sphere](http://youtu.be/L2YRZbRSD1k)

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well a flight simulator should be harder than this, because in the video you linked it seems that the character (and so the camera "following" it) isn't actually moving, the sphere representing the planet is only rotating around its own center, so the camera isn't moving i think, it's just the sphere well positionned and simply rotating

If you want a "flight simulator" with a fixed height above the planet, it seems to be the simplest way to accomplish it

Answer (score 0):

You are right. I want the sphere to rotate. This is what i've got so far:

```
float rotationX = 0;
float rotationY = 0;
float velocityX = 0;
float velocityY = 0;

boolean[] keys = new boolean[255];

void setup(){
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  background(150);

  if(keys[LEFT]) {
    velocityY += 0.04;
  }
  if(keys[RIGHT]) {
    velocityY -= 0.04;
  }
  if(keys[UP]) {
    velocityX += 0.04;
  }
  if(keys[DOWN]) {
    velocityX -= 0.04;
  }

  translate(width/2, height/2 + 160, 325);
  rotateX( radians(-rotationX) );
  rotateY( radians(-rotationY) );
  sphere(150);

  rotationX += velocityX;
  rotationY += velocityY;
  velocityX *= 0.95;
  velocityY *= 0.95;
}

void keyPressed() {
  keys[keyCode] = true;
}

void keyReleased() {
  keys[keyCode] = false;
}
```

So the main problem is that the X Y Z axises are rotating with the sphere. Walk around on my sphere and compare it to the behaviour of the sphere in this example:

[collinhover.github.io/kaiopua/](http://collinhover.github.io/kaiopua/)

The axises in this example are always fixed. I don't know how to explain it better.